# OrientDB Query by edge property

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases

I have two vertex classes: Location and User and I have two edges also: Friend and GoingTo. A User can be 'Friend' with another User and a User can also 'GoingTo' a Location. The edge GoingTo has a datetime property called going_date with the date the user is going to the Location.

I want to return every ‘Location’ that has a in(“GoingTo”) edge from an ‘User’ that is a (“Friend”) of a specific starting ‘User’ (#12:11 as example).

What I have here is all locations but without the date property of goingTo...

```
SELECT expand(both('Friend').out('goingTo')) FROM #12:11
```

How can I query by this edge property?

Answer (score 2):

You can filter on edge's property:

`SELECT expand(both('Friend').outE('goingTo')[going_date='2015-01-01'].inV()) FROM #12:11`

Comment: Hey Lvca Tks for the help.... I tried this way but it didn't work...
When I use without the [going_date='xxx'] it works but with it doesn't.

Comment: @lvca what is the role of   .inV() function here

Comment: To get the incoming vertex when you're on an edge.

Comment: We're wondering whether to store data in an edge's properties. @user2962069, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Little late but since this was a high result for my google search, thought I'd link the answer I found [on another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570467/orientdb-query-edge-property-by-value).

My use case, and I believe a wide category of use cases leaning on recursion, *has* to store data in edge properties.

For OP, it should be

```
SELECT expand(both('Friend').out('goingTo')) FROM #12:11 
WHERE out_goingTo[0].going_date = '2015-01-01'
```

This seems like a case where you'd have 1-many "going to" edges, so it could be

`WHERE out_goingTo[0-100]` for a range or

`WHERE out_goingTo[0,5,10]` for a set.

HTH!