# How can I query an edge property by value?

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases

I'm using OrientDB (Community-2.0.9) and have two vertices: Person and University and one edge: isStudent. The edge isStudent has the property 'mark' as float. Person --isStudent--> University.

Now I want to select all persons, where the mark is greater than 3.0, but I got no results, but if I query for equality I got two results.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this?

Queries:

```
SELECT FROM PERSON WHERE out_isStudent.mark = 3.4 --> two results
SELECT FROM PERSON WHERE out_isStudent.mark > 3.0 --> no results
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you:

```
select out_isStudent.mark from Person
```

you see that it returns the list **[3.4]** instead of **3.4**

The query that should not work is the first since you're comparing **[3.4] == 3.4**

You can achieve what you want with:

```
select from Person where out_isStudent[0].mark > 3
```