# How do I find edges whose embeddedset contains the value 'x'?

Tags: sql, graph, graph-theory, orientdb, traversal

I have the following graph structure:

```
CREATE CLASS Role EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS Resource EXTENDS V;
CREATE CLASS is_allowed EXTENDS E;
CREATE PROPERTY is_allowed.actions EMBEDDEDSET STRING;

CREATE EDGE is_allowed FROM #19:1 TO #22:33 CONTENT {'actions':['read', 'write', 'execute']}
```

I'm now trying to find objects that have a specific permission, So I tried:

```
SELECT inE('is_allowed')['read' in actions)] FROM Resource WHERE name = 'Some Resource'
SELECT expand(inE('is_allowed')[actions contains 'read']) FROM Resource
SELECT expand(inE('is_allowed')['read'=actions]) FROM Resource
```

But got no results, To sanity check I did:

```
SELECT expand(inE('is_allowed')) FROM Resource
```

and I do get two results showing the inbound edges.

I looked at this SO answer ([OrientDB Query by edge property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29157991/orientdb-query-by-edge-property)) and can easily filter the edges when it's a single string preperty, but not sure if it's possible or how to filter when using an embeddedset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a nested SELECT statement:

```
select from (
    SELECT expand(inE('is_allowed')) FROM Resource
  ) where actions contains "write"
```

EDIT:
If you need roles or resource, you can expand the in and out.

for roles:

```
select expand(out) from (
    SELECT expand(inE('is_allowed')) FROM Resource
  ) where actions contains "read"
```

and for resources:

```
select expand(in) from (
    SELECT expand(inE('is_allowed')) FROM Resource
  ) where actions contains "read"
```

BYE

Comment: Yeap, thanks, this is what I ended up doing, pity I can't just do it without the expand :(